# How to set limit & Order in TYPO3 HMENU

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In below TYPO3 script code get pages list from others menu item

I want to set order by latest pages with a limit parameter(limit=5)

special directory include submenu entries and display it at home page

```
[page|uid = 1]
lib.content_6.stdWrap.preCObject = HMENU
lib.content_6.stdWrap.preCObject {

    1 = TMENU

    wrap = <div class="wpContentElement wpReferenceList"><ul>|</ul></div>
    special = directory
    special.value = 94,95,97,378,445
    includeNotInMenu = 1
    special.range = 1|-2

    1 {
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">|</li>
        NO.stdWrap.cObject = COA
        NO.stdWrap.cObject {

            10 = TEXT
            10 {
                field = title
                wrap = <div>|</div>
            }
            20 = FILES
            20 {
                references {
                    table = pages
                    uid.field = uid
                    fieldName = tx_mask_referenceimage
                }
                renderObj = IMAGE
                renderObj {
                    file.import.data = file:current:uid
                    file.treatIdAsReference = 1
                    file.height = 850c
                    file.width  = 850c
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
[end]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximum can be done with `maxItems`, but there is no option for your own ordering. You might be able to abuse `additionalWhere`.

A cleaner solution would be to implement an own `itemArrayProcFunc`.

```
1 = TMENU
1 {
    maxItems = 5
    // additionalWhere = ORDER BY tstamp desc

    itemArrayProcFunc = user_menuItemArrayProcFunc->process
}
```